# Run JUnit tests dynamically and view results in eclipse JUnit view

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm running my JUnit tests programmatically

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
Result result = junit.run(MyTest1.class, MyTest2.class);
```

Is there a way of getting that `result` and show it in the eclipse JUnit viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Someone had a similar situation and suggested calling

> org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IWorkbenchPage, URI, String,
>   boolean)

[Open JUnit View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199206/2103767)